# Saleor front-end installation

Tags: python, django, saleor

I am trying to install saleor front-end package from github.The documentation is outdated and i get an error when i try

```
>>>nmp start
Error: Environment variable API_URI not set
```

I found this variable in different places but did not know what to change, and where to set it

EDIT:Solved.just in case somebody is going through the same problem
in webpack>config.base.js

```
process.env.API_URI = 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/'
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I fixed this by setting environment variable before running npm; start with:

```
export API_URI=http://localhost:8000/graphql/
```

on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

create a file in the root directory of /saleor-storefront called ".env" and write inside:

```
API_URI=http://localhost:8000/graphql/
```

This will create an environment variable called API_URI with the value 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/'

Answer (score 0):

Create `.env` file in a root directory or set environment variables with following values:

> `API_URI` (required) - URI of a running instance of Saleor GraphQL API. If you are running Saleor locally with the default settings, set `API_URI` to: `http://localhost:8000/graphql/`.

> `APP_MOUNT_URI` - URI at which the Dashboard app will be mounted. E.g. If you set `APP_MOUNT_URI` to `/dashboard/`, your app will be mounted at `http://localhost:9000/dashboard/`.

> `STATIC_URL` - URL where the static files are located. E.g. if you use S3 bucket, you should set it to the bucket's URL. By default Saleor assumes you serve static files from the root of your site at `http://localhost:9000/`.

[Saleor on Github: How to configure the Dashboard](https://github.com/saleor/saleor-dashboard)